# MinIO integration with KMS using Java SDKs

Tags: java, amazon-kms, minio

I am new to MinIO and trying  to use `Java based SDKs` (MinIO and/or Amazon SDK).

For normal files it is working fine, but when I try uploading a file with `SSE-C` (i.e. with KMS client provided key id), I am getting this error (in case of Amazon SDK):

```
com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: A header you provided implies functionality that is not implemented (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 501; Error Code: NotImplemented; Request ID: 15ECD0D30FAA19D1; S3 Extended Request ID: fa2f2a07-5d03-4298-ae9c-9fe3e87c22e6), S3 Extended Request ID: fa2f2a07-5d03-4298-ae9c-9fe3e87c22e6     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1695)  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1350)    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1101)    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:758)     at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:732)  at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:714)   at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:674)
```

I have also tried the sample code on minIO cookbook using **MinioClient** and it still gives the NotImplemented exception.

The `KMS on MinIO` server was configured using the MinIO quickstart KMS guide. Also SSE using KMS auto-encryption seems to be working fine